# Control sound with Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

How to properly pause or stop audio track with javascript?, I tried this:

```
var track1 = new Audio('track1.mp3');

$('#play').click(function() {
track1.play();
});

$('#stop').click(function() {
track1.stop();
});
```

It plays but can't make it stop, I'm basically trying to make an small player with the basic options, super simple without using any framework.

Answer (score 1):

Audio elements don't have a "stop" method. I think you may be looking for `track1.pause()` instead.

Reference to HTMLMediaElement methods and properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement